# User editable checkbox after submitted form Symfony

Tags: symfony

I have to make a profile page where's the registered user next to his additional data also able to tick and untick a checkbox to receive something and then save the profile.

When the profile is saved, the database receives the clicked checkbox and sets to `1`. If it's not, then it remains null. This way it's all good.

Then the horror begins because I'm not able to untick it and submit the profile again because the 1 remains forever. Even if I update another data, the value is `1`.

```
Form:
->add(
      'isYes', CheckboxType::class,
       ['required' => false]
      )

Controller:
if($form->get('isYes')) {
    $user->setIsYes(true);
} 
else {
    $user->setIsYes(false);
}
```

HTML :

```
<input type="hidden" id="yes" name="said_yes" value="0"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="yes" name="said_yes" value="1"> 

Interface:
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getIsYes(): bool
{
    return boolval($this->isYes);
}

/**
 * @param bool $isYes
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setIsYes(bool $isYes): User
{
    $this->isYes = $isYes;

    return $this;
}
```

How can I untick the checkbox (even to keep the checkbox checked if it's checked) and change the value to `0`?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$form->get('isYes')->getData()`.

Inside an if statement `$form->get('isYes')` will always resolve in true, because it will return form field (not it's data).

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately only changes from 1 to 0 and that's it. I did try to add value at the form, also changing a bit the code but nothing worked :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally here's my solution if someone needs it in the future:

```
->add(
            'isYes', CheckboxType::class,
            ['required' => false,
                'value' => true]
        )
```

I have removed the values from the HTML part and the the IF statement and also changed the boolval to bool, **only set the value to true** and TADA! Sends new value each time to the database when it's ticked or unticked.